# Cant find my Main_Activity.xml file in my latest version of android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I create a new project in Android Studio it does not create any Main_Activity.xml file. How can I make my project without it or what should I do to fix this?

I made a new layout file and create some layouts in it but still does not find that Main_Activity.xml file. ( My Android studio is up to date)

Comment: are you sure you're looking for main_activity.xml? its activity_main.xml which is created.

Comment: yeah, I recently  downloaded the latest version of android studio and whenever I create new project in it there is no "layout" directory in it and if I create one of that name I get no Avtivity-main.xml file in it. what should I do ?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your project files structure to the question.